# How to automate next() call in every route function? (express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Hi I am facing the problem that I need to log each incomming request and the associated responses in my database. My current solution looks like the following:

./routes/customer.js

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    req.allCustomers = await fetchAllCustomers();
    res.status(200).send(req.allCustomers);
    next();  // <- this is my personal problem
});
```

./middleware/logging.js

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    db.query(
        `INSERT INTO logging SET ?`, 
         { 
            request: JSON.stringify([req.body, req.params]), 
            response: JSON.stringify(req.response) 
         }
    );
}
```

routes declaration

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use('/api/customers', customers); // <- ROUTE ./routes/customer.js
    app.use(logging); // <- MIDDLEWARE ./middleware/logging.js
}
```

I already mentioned my problem in my first piece of code. It is really repetitive to call `next()` in every route manually and I would like to avoid this. I already tried to load the middleware before all routes, call `next()` in the middleware function and execute my db query afterwards but I do not have the response at this point because of the async functionality.

Is there any way to handle this situation or will I need keep calling `next()` at the end of each route function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to call `next()` from your routes, you cannot have middleware run after them. It needs to be placed before. But can you get the response inside a middleware that runs before the route? The answer is yes!

It may be a little hacky, but since your route uses `res.send()`, you can use that to your advantage. By running before your route, your middleware can hijack that `res.send` function, to make it do other stuff.

**./routes/customer.js**

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    req.allCustomers = await fetchAllCustomers();
    res.send(req.allCustomers); // We'll hijack this
});
```

**./middleware/logging.js**

```
module.exports = function (shouldBeLoggedFunc) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    if (shouldBeLoggedFunc(req)) {
      // Store the original send method
      const _send = res.send;
      // Override it
      res.send = function (body) {
        // Reset it
        res.send = _send;
        // Actually send the response
        res.send(body);
        // Log it (console.log for the demo)
        console.log(`INSERT INTO logging SET ?`, {
          request: JSON.stringify([req.body, req.params]),
          response: JSON.stringify(body)
        });
      };
    }
    next();
  };
};
```

**routes declaration**

```
function shouldBeLogged(req) {
  // Here, check the route and method and decide whether you want to log it
  console.log(req.method, req.path); // e.g. GET /api/customers
  return true;
}

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(logging(shouldBeLogged)); // <- Place this before your routes
    app.use('/api/customers', customers);
};
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Great thanks! Wondering why this is not a "default" possibility for node.

Answer (score 0):

when you use express.Router class like you already did and then use this code

```js
app.use('/api/customers', customers);
```

you don't have to write 'next()' inside callback function in router.get .

there is an example 
create a router file named birds.js in the app directory, with the following content:

```js
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About birds')
})

module.exports = router
```

Then, load the router module in the app:

```js
var birds = require('./birds')

// ...

app.use('/birds', birds)
```

Comment: I am facing an  important problem with this solution. It is not possible to use the ```req.params``` and also the response is not included.